# Prolific PL2303 ceased working

Tags: macos, usb

On my MacBook Air (running 10.11.2), all my Prolific PL2303 USB-RS232 Adapters (USB VID_067B&PID_2303) ceased working out of the blue, literally over night. I have no idea what caused this.

The adapter shows up when running `ioreg -p IOUSB` as

```
+-o IOUSBHostDevice@14200000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x10000063a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (37 ms), retain 11>
```

The devices /dev/tty.usbserial and /dev/cu.usbserial are still created, but `screen /dev/tty.usbserial` won't work. screen opens without an error, but I can't do nothing. screen does not react to keystrokes.

I tried these adapters with Windows / Putty and everything works as supposed.

I uninstalled the old drivers by running

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/ProlificUsbSerial.kext
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/*PL2303*.*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/*ProlificUSbSerial*.*
```

and installed the latest Prolific driver from http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41, but no luck.

`sudo dmesg` shows

> PL-2303/X V1.5.0 start, Prolific

No other errors.

Still, no show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Download the new package [PL2303_MacOSX_1.6.1_20160309.zip](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given that I'm in a hurry and need to configure some devices I discarded all my Prolific based USB adapters and purchased a couple of FTDI based devices, which work flawlessly with El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything myself. The only thing I actually got to work was buying drivers from Mac-serial-USB.com I do believe what the website was. After I loaded the new driver from them. It was like 8$ it worked perfect which made me extremely mad because I shouldn't have to pay some random company for a driver that should already work.

Comment: Did you experience the same symptoms as described above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you disable the SIP in the recovery? I recently updated to 10.11.2 from 10.11. Previously I had disable it but after update, it was enable again by Apple.

1. Restart laptop, press command+R to go into recovery.
2. Open 'Terminal' in recovery
3. check SIP status, type> csrutil status
4. if it is enable, then disable it by typing> csrutil disable
5. reboot

hope it helps.

edit: here's a link to understand SIP protection >> http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mac-security-el-captan-rootless/

Comment: as stated above, I don't have the problem that the kext doesn't get loaded. In fact, the kernel message quoted above states that there aren't any kext related problems, so I don't know how disabling SIP would do any good.